# Use of % (urlencoding) in PartitionKey and RowKey with filtering

Tags: azure-storage

I am url encoding strings that I use as PartitionKey's and RowKey's (a lazy way to avoid use of invalid characters like `/?`). They get stored fine but when I try to use WCF Data Services filters like `PartitionKey eq 'abc%20def'` the lookups fail (do not return any results). Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

Comment: The above refers to when I put the expression into the Visual Studio Table explorer. If I write C# Linq code it works so must be a feature of VS.

Comment: Could you please post some code to reproduce - using the latest SDK. Thanks.